QML Module not found (Qt location)
When I try to import QtLocation:
import QtLocation
import QtPositioning

I get this error:

QML Module not found (Qt location)

How do I solve this?

You must include the Qt Positioning Module in your build file. Here is a Qt resource explaining how to do that:
Using Qt Positioning
For, e.g., CMake, you have to add this:
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Location)
target_link_libraries(mytarget PRIVATE Qt6::Location)

